# Which Sefer deserves "The Artscroll treatment"?

Tags: torah-study, jewish-books, translation, english

B"H, Artscroll has been very busy producing a large plethora of translated Sefarim to the general public. I was wondering which Sefarim should get translated. There is several factors to this; practically, a Sefer that *needs* to become more out there, or whatever other reason. Combining these factors, which Sefer or Sefarim deserves "the artscroll treatment"?

Personally, I think Sifrei Chofetz Chaim (Torat Habayit, Chovot Hashmera, etc.) would be a great addition. (especially since Chofetz Chaim and Shmeras Halashon have already been translated)